# В мобильной версии картинка вылезает при параметре display: none

Tags: javascript, html, css

Вот такой код с действующего сайта: `https://codepen.io/CeReRa/pen/qYYOeO`
Проблема в том, что в мобильной версии сайта изображение, находящееся внутри блока, вылезает и видно сразу при загрузке страницы. Но у меня же стоит `display: none`!
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: >>В чем может быть проблема?<< переопределение display в других классах и стилях элементов

Comment: Я новичок. Объясните, пожалуйста, как это решить.

Comment: Хром в разработчике не показывает такой проблемы. Там все хорошо показывает. А именно на телефоне вылезает. Как там проверить и выяснить в каком месте оно переопределяет?

Comment: а на телефоне какой браузер?

Comment: На ноутбуке не удалось воспроизвести. Я так понимаю, нужно говорить  не в "мобильной версии", а "на телефоне", и указывать какой браузер на телефоне, как сказано выше

Comment: Да, прошу прощения, на телефоне хром 66.0.3359.126

Answer (score 1):

Отталкиваясь только от информации что вы выложили, я могу лишь показать что произошло, чтобы в дальнейшем у вас не было таких вопросов:

Пример странички:

```
Смотреть сюда:
<div class="MyStyleName">Невидимый текст</div>
```

Пример стиля:

```
.MyStyleName { 

  display: none;

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cwd04vxv/

Это идеальный вариант, то что вы ожидаете. Далее, я предлагаю не меняя ничего, добавить небольшой стиль:

```
div.MyStyleName {

  display: block;

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mz1LksL4/

И что же мы увидим? А увидим то что теперь всё что было невидимым стало видимым. Непорядок - скажете вы. Нет, всё правильно. Причина такого поведения в теории. Для того чтобы понять что происходит, вам надо понять что такое селекторы. Именно селектор играет ключевую роль. В данном примере селектор вида "Что угодно с классом MyStyleName" является более общим чем "div с класом MyStyleName", именно поэтому второй вариант является более приоритетным. (он конкретнее чем первый).

Так же, смена приоритета селектора может быть достугнута принуждением к перезаписи свойства !important, как пример:

https://jsfiddle.net/xgpxhbyw/

Мы просто принудили интерпретатор не смотреть на привычный приоритет селекторов, и явно сказали что за свойство и значение тут является главным.

Надеюсь, вы не будете задавать впредь вопросов в стиле "Почему это произошло?"

Comment: И да, и нет. Во-первых, нет кода с приоритетами селекторов. Все односложно, ничего конкретезирующего по типу div.class нет. Во-вторых, со свойством !impotant перестает работать модальное окно. А оно все же нужно.

Comment: @CeReRa, я вам указал где у вас ошибка, что там у вас в коде - не имеет значения. Ошибка именно в том, что вы подключаете ещё один стиль (для мобильной версии сайта) и он перекрывает ваш основной стиль. Если стиль мобильной версии такой кривой, правьте его. Про !important - я показал как именно приоритеты селекторов влияют на картину в целом. Более того, !important - это исключение из правил, к нему очень неоднозначно относятся, потому что использование его, говорит о том что вы пытаетесь сделать костыль, либо подружить несколько версий стилей.

Comment: >>ничего конкретезирующего по типу div.class нет<< я привёл пример с конкретным селектором. У вас может быть что угодно, например, div.span .MyClass { ... } вот вам пример ещё одного конкретного селектора, вернее, двух селекторов, один и которых имеет больший приоритет.